# How to Remove multiple records from Datatable in vb.net 2008 not from database in local table?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I have datatable in vb.net 2008 has 40000 rows. i want to delete 1000 rows from that datatable not from database.
i want to do this without looping
I know remove and removeat but both need looping.
is there any way i can achieve this thing ?

Comment: Please do not ask essentially the same question again. It would be better if you edited your original questions and added details to it.

Comment: ok sorry i will do that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use YourDataTable.Take(39000) or YourDataTable.Skip(1000)
Or if there is a critera that should match. Use select , YourDataTable.Select(x => x.Something = "yourvalue"). But this will also loop the collection.